# Error "not a valid month" SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Buenas tardes;

Estoy realizando un ejercicio para mi curso de Base de Datos, nos pasaron un script para crear las tablas y hacer los inserts de los elementos (uso el Oracle Application Express). Pero a la hora de ejecutar cualquier insert me sale el siguiente error:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

El código de la tablas y de los inserts es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE CURSOS
( Codigo NUMBER, 
  Nombre VARCHAR2(20), 
  Cod_Profe NUMBER, 
  Max_Alumn NUMBER, 
  Fecha_Inic DATE, 
  Fecha_Fin DATE, 
  Num_Horas NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT Cod_Curso_PK PRIMARY KEY (Codigo),    
  CONSTRAINT Cod_Profe_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Profe)
    REFERENCES PROFESORADO(Codigo)
);


INSERT INTO CURSOS (Codigo, Nombre, Max_Alumn, Fecha_Inic, Fecha_Fin, Num_Horas) VALUES 
(1, 'Curso 1', 30, '01/01/2011', '31/12/2011', 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es probable que el formato de fecha sea "MM/DD/YYYY", haz la prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO CURSOS (Codigo, Nombre, Max_Alumn, Fecha_Inic, Fecha_Fin, Num_Horas) VALUES 
(1, 'Curso 1', 30, TO_DATE('01/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('31/12/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de la cadena que representa las fechas usar [TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm); tanto para los `insert`, `update`, etc.

Es como a continuación en tu sentencia que colocaste

```
INSERT INTO CURSOS (Codigo, Nombre, Max_Alumn, Fecha_Inic, Fecha_Fin, Num_Horas) VALUES 
(1, 'Curso 1', 30, TO_DATE('01/01/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('31/12/2011', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 100);
```

Observa que se indica cada elemento en que posición se encuentra y el separador:

- **DD**: Día.
- **MM**: Mes.
- **YYYY**: Año.
- **/**: Para este caso el separador de cada elemento es el */*; dependiendo tu sistema deberás indcarlo

*El error que te sale se debe a que el formato a interpretarse debe ser MM/DD/YYYY; por tanto el primer elemento por default Oracle lo considera el Mes; esto depende como esta configurado; con TO_DATE "nos evitamos" saber este formato; y en caso de cambiar de ambiente no te preocuparias ya que la función hara el cambio*

Comment: podría cambiar el formato de la tabla para que coincida con el de los inserts, me sería mucho más cómodo.

Comment: Es mejor usar el formato ANSI que funciona en Oracle, SQL Server etc. 
Por ejemplo DATE '2011-01-01'